# Best way to store user information on android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to save user data that is fetched from a server. It's much like a social network with friends to store and user data like name, email, etc.. I was thinking of creating a custom class to handle this or adding these to a sqlitedatabase.

Performance oriented, what is the best way to save these? the sqliteDatabase or the object? I'm thinking that creating objects for every friend the user has, will eat up a lot of memory?

I would like to save these so the app only has to update them when they are changed on the server, saving on data usage and improving performance.

Comment: Take a look into https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Comment: I read the page, but this looks like saving the users data online. I would like to save a lot of data in the cache to improve on the speed of the app and save on bandwith

Comment: Well you read wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user information to be available even when he is offline , you have two options.

1. SQLite database
2. Shared Preferences

If you have a lot of information to store , like  a list of friends or a list of tasks , then use the SQLite database.
If you have to store little information for ex - mobile number , email address , user id then use shared preferences.

There are other alternatives to the SQLite database where you do not have to write queries.  For ex [realm](https://realm.io/)

Answer (score 1):

To save data to local memory in android, you have two options:

1. SQlite DB
2. SharedPrefrences

To make it simple I would say,

If you have complex and relatively more data, use SQlite.

If you just want to store basic info. in terms of key-value pair, use SharedPreferences.